# Run-time error '1004', Application-defined or object-defined error when setting variable =cell.offset

Tags: excel, vba, offset

This is my code. It runs through a list of values starting at `Cell L1`, finds them in another worksheet and then finds an offset cell. If that cell contains `"TEMPLATE"` it is to remove the value from the original list.

```
Sub Removetemplate()

Dim x As Variant
Dim myString As String
Dim temprng As Range
Dim cell As Object

  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  Worksheets("WorkingSO").Activate
  NumRows = Range("L2", Range("L2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  ' Select cell L2.
  Set SORNG = Range("L2")
  SORNG.Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  Worksheets("Sales Orders").Activate
  For x = 1 To NumRows

        For Each cell In Sheet1.Cells
                If cell.Value = SORNG.Value Then
                    Set temprng = cell.Offset(28, -17)
                    myString = temprng.Value
                        If InStr(myString, "TEMPLATE") > 0 Then
                            SORNG.ClearContents
                        End If
                End If
        Next



     ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
     Set SORNG = SORNG.Offset(1, 0)
  Next



End Sub
```

The `1004 error` occurs at the line `Set temprng = cell.Offset(28, -17)`. Im not 100% sure but I believe that it works the first time through but fails on the second loop.

Comment: there are no instances of cell being in a row less than 17 where cell.value = SORNG.value

Comment: @ConnorHoward put a breakpoint on the `Set tmprng` line, hit the breakpoint and type `?cell.Address`. You're running into an error, there *is* a problem with the row number.

Comment: no. and the second value in the offset adjusts the column not the row. but its closest column is Z (26)

Comment: oops you are correct, sorry but you should do what @Mat'sMug stated.  Just to verify.

Comment: Also please stick `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and declare every variable you're using. That will eliminate the risk of a typo fudging everything up.

Comment: thanks for the input. I used the answer from @user3598756 and that fixed my problem the way that you were steering me towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it because `For Each cell In Sheet1.Cells` loops through *all* cells of `Sheet1` and therefore it also loop through cell belonging to column 1 to 17 which causes   `cell.Offset(28, -17)` to fail since it'd try to reach a "negative column" cell

moreover you must avoid `Activate`/`Select` coding habits and use fully qualified range reference

try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Removetemplate()
    Dim SOCell As Range, WSOCell As Range
    Dim WSORng As Range

    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    With Worksheets("WorkingSO")
        Set WSORng = .Range("L2", .Range("L2").End(xlDown)) 'set "WorkingSO" worksheet range to loop through
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sales Orders") '<--| reference "Sales Orders" worksheet
        For Each WSOCell In WSORng '<--| loop through WSORng cells
            For Each SOCell In .Columns("R").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through currently referenced worksheet (i.e. "Sales Orders") column "R" cells with any constant value
                If SOCell.Value = WSOCell.Value Then '<--| if current "Sales Orders" cell value matches current "WorkingSO" one
                    If InStr(SOCell.Offset(28, -17), "TEMPLATE") > 0 Then WSOCell.ClearContents '<--| if "Sales Orders" cell offsetted 28 rows down and 17 columns left form current one has "TEMPLATE", then clear current "WorkingSO" cell
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

where you have to change `.Columns("R")` to the actual "Sales Orders" worksheet column index you want to look for "WorkingSO" column "L" values in

Comment: Thanks. this did the trick. I am very new to this and am only now trying to adapt the cleanest practices of avoiding active/select. I still dont understand how it would have gotten to "cell.Offset(28, -17)" with a value of 17 or less if every instance of "cell.Value = SORNG.Value" occurs after column Y

Comment: You are welcome. Wouldn't say why it got to such columns indexes since I don't have your data. But you could step through your previous code (F8 key) and query immediate window (?cell.Value, cell.Address, cell.Parent.Name) to see what's actually happening.